# String to datagridview

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Not getting info in datagridview.
if i had try in multi textbox its fine but not in datagridview

```
public String Accountlocked()
        {
            //DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://Mytechnet.com");
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://User");
            DirectorySearcher Dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);



            Dsearch.Filter = "(&(&(&(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)>>(lockoutTime:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=4294967295))))))";


            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {

                foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in Dsearch.FindAll())
                {

                    sw.WriteLine("{0}", (GetProperty(sResultSet, "samaccountname")));
                    sw.WriteLine("{0}", (GetProperty(sResultSet, "name")));

                }
                return sw.ToString();

            }

        }
```

On button

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = Accountlocked().ToList();
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a string converted to a list of chars as your gridview's datasource?

Comment: `string.ToList()` returns `List<char>`. What are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public DataTable Accountlocked()
        {
           //DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://Mytechnet.com");
           DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://User");
           DirectorySearcher Dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

           Dsearch.Filter = "(&(&(&(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)>>(lockoutTime:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:=4294967295))))))";

           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           dt.Columns.Add("AccountName");
           dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in Dsearch.FindAll())
                {
                   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();          
                   dr[0] = (GetProperty(sResultSet, "samaccountname"));
                   dr[1] = (GetProperty(sResultSet, "name"));
                   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                return dt;
            }
        }


dataGridView1.DataSource = Accountlocked();
```

Comment: i receive error {"The server is not operational.\r\n"} under foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in Dsearch.FindAll())

Comment: I had debug and found no value pass in, would anyone can why whats wrong in code